# Upload csv file to aws s3 bucket directly from a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, xlsx, fs

Happy weekend all,

I'm working on a task that fetches data from an API then store them into a csv file then from there directly upload to AWS S3 bucket. I've tried several ways but I'm currently stuck at the very last point. Any help would be much appreciate

My code below would demonstrate most of the problems and also what I've been trying so far.

- First, I will fetch the data from an API

```
async systems() {
        const endpoint = sampleEndPoints.SYSTEMS
        return this.aggregateEndpoint(endpoint)
    }
```

- Second, I will get the data that fetched back and put them in a csv file as buffer. (Because I have to store them in `fs.createReadStream` later on)

```
// generate JSON to Buffer
    async generateCsvToBuffer(json){
            const {aws} = this.config
            var ws = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(json)

            var wb = xlsx.utils.book_new();

          await xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Systems')

            const csvParsed = xlsx.write(wb, { type: 'buffer'})


            return csvParsed;
    }
```

- Third, I get the `buffer data` from that `csvParsed` in order to `upload` it to the amazon AWS S3. The problem is right here, that the `Body: fileStream.path` is supposed to show the *content* of the file but unfortunately, it logs out like this which coming from the `fs.createReadStream`

`'{"type":"Buffer","data":[80,75,3,4,10,0,0,0,0,0,249,117,199,78,214,146,124`

```
 async uploadSample(file){
        const {aws} = this.config

        AWS.config.update({
          secretAccessKey: aws.secretAccessKey,
          accessKeyId: aws.accessKeyId,
          region: 'us-east-2'
        })


        const bufferObject = new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(file))


     /*** WE NEED THE FILE SYSTEM IN ORDER TO STORE  */
        const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(bufferObject)


        const uploadParams = {Bucket: aws.bucket, Key: aws.key, Body: fileStream.path}


        const s3 = new AWS.S3()
       await s3.upload(uploadParams,null,function(error, file){
          if(error){
            console.log(error)
          } else {
            console.log('Successfully uploaded')
          }
        })
    }
```

- All of my function will be executed in the `server.js`. So if you have a look at this then you can actually get the whole picture of the problem

```
app.get('/systems/parsed', async(req, res) => {
    const Sample = await Sample()

//Fetch the data from an API 
    const systems = await Cache.remember('systems', async() => {
        return Sample.systems()
    })
    const integration = await IntegrationInstance()

/** GET THE RESPONSE DATA AND PUT THEM IN A CSV FILE*/
    const result = await integration.generateCsvToBuffer(systems)

    const aws = await AwsInstance()

/*** GET THE SYSTEMS FILE (CSV FILE) THEN UPLOAD THEM INTO THE AWS S3 BUCKET*/

    const awsUpload = await aws.uploadWorkedWithBuffer(result)


    return res.send(awsUpload);
})
```

- **My only concern here is that, the file has successfully uploaded to the Amazon AWS S3, but the content of the file is still in Buffer. Any help on the existing function / any shorter way would much appreciate.**
- Here's my summarize again: fetch data from a server -> put on the Csv file as buffer BUT from a web browser -> and from there upload it to Amazon AWS S3 bucket -> Problem is file is uploaded but the content of the file is still in buffer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are making things more complicated than necessary here. According to the documentation [.upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) you can pass a buffer to the upload directly instead of creating a stream from the buffer.  I suspect your underlying issue is passing the path from the stream instead of the stream itself though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesstion Deadron, but I actually tried to add the filestream itself but it didn't work out :(

Comment: Just pass in the buffer without trying to create the stream.

Comment: I tried it, and the result is still the same, the content of the file is still 

```'{"type":"Buffer","data":[80,75,3,4,10,0,0,0,0,0,249,117,199,78,214,146,124```

Comment: I suspect this is because your file param may already be a Buffer and you calling JSON.stringify on it causes it to become the string you see.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it.

- First, whenever you created the function `generateCsvToBuffer` remember to have a `bookType` on your `wb` (Workbook) in order for s3 to recognize it. The function should be something like this

```
    async generateCsvToBuffer(json){
            const {aws} = this.config
            var ws = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(json)

            var wb = xlsx.utils.book_new();

          await xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Systems')

            const csvParsed = xlsx.write(wb, { type: 'buffer', bookType: 'csv'})

            return csvParsed;
    }
```

- Second, you have to import `Content-Disposition: attachment` into the `uploadParams` for the Aws Configuration

```
 async uploadSample(file){
        const {aws} = this.config

        AWS.config.update({
          secretAccessKey: aws.secretAccessKey,
          accessKeyId: aws.accessKeyId,
          region: 'us-east-2'
        })


        const bufferObject = new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(file))


     /*** WE NEED THE FILE SYSTEM IN ORDER TO STORE  */
        const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(bufferObject)


        const uploadParams = {Bucket: aws.bucket, Key: aws.key, Body: fileStream.path}


        const s3 = new AWS.S3()
       await s3.upload(uploadParams,null,function(error, file){
          if(error){
            console.log(error)
          } else {
            console.log('Successfully uploaded')
          }
        })
    }
```